# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException and showInputDialog

Tags: java, string, while-loop, joptionpane

this is a homework problem.. I'm working on a program that uses `JOptionPane` to count votes, until Q or q is entered and the vote count stops. It then launches a `showConfirmDialog` which asks the user if they really want to quit. the main task of the program has been accomplished, but one of the instructions states that on the showInputDialog, any entry that is not Y, y, N, n, Q, or q will be ignored.

I'm having trouble with this because, for some reason any time any button on the dialog box is clicked, the program shuts down. The rest of the program works fine, but when I run it, it gives a compiling error notification and I end up having this problem.

Here is my code. Any idea what's going on here? Thanks for any assistance.

EDIT - just so you know, the `System.out.println("HI");` line was just there so I could determine if the problem was with the entire if statement of the continue statement that was in its place.

EDIT #2 - I posted my edit of the code using your advice (at least how I interpreted it) below the first program (it is now `VoteCount2`).

EDIT #3 - I reformatted it and tried to follow your advice. If I did something wrong I'm sorry but I just don't know what to do.

edit #4 - Here is how I got it working..

```
Do { String voteString = ""; 
voteString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 'Y' to vote yes, 'N' to vote no, or 'Q' to quit voting", "Vote Now!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
 if (voteString == null || voteString.length() == 0) continue;
 else if(voteString.toLowerCase().equals("y")) 
yesVotes++;
 else if (voteString.toLowerCase().equals("n")) 
noVotes++;
```

rest of old program

```
           package javaapplication16;

           import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

           public class VoteCount {

           public static void main(String[] args) {

           int yesVotes = 0, noVotes = 0, totalVotes = 0;
           totalVotes = yesVotes + noVotes;
           char vote;
           int reply = 1;
           int option = 0;
           {
           do {
           String voteString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 'Y' to vote yes, 'N'  to vote no, or 'Q' to quit voting", "Vote Now!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
           vote = voteString.charAt(0);
           if (vote == 'Y' || vote == 'y')
           yesVotes++;
           if (vote == 'N' || vote == 'n')
           noVotes++;
           if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
           System.out.println("HI");
           if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
           continue;
           if (option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION)
           continue;
             {
            }

           if (vote == 'Q' || vote == 'q')
           {
           reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Quit?", "Warning!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
           if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "yes " + yesVotes + " no " + noVotes + " total " + totalVotes);
           else if (reply != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    continue;
            }
           } while (reply != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

           }
        }
    }


package javaapplication16;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class VoteCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int yesVotes = 0, noVotes = 0, totalVotes = 0;
totalVotes = yesVotes + noVotes;
char vote;
    int reply = 1;
{
    do {
 String voteString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 'Y' to vote yes, 'N' to vote no, or 'Q' to quit voting", "Vote Now!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
 vote = voteString.charAt(0);
 if (voteString == null || voteString.length() == 0)
vote = 'q';
if (voteString.toLowerCase().equals("y"))
     yesVotes++;
if (voteString.toLowerCase().equals("n"))
        noVotes++;

        {
    }

if (voteString.toLowerCase().equals("q"))
{
    reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Quit?", "Warning!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "yes " + yesVotes + " no " + noVotes + " total " + totalVotes);
    else if (reply != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
continue;
        }
    } while (reply != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: homework tag, if it;s a homework problem

Comment: where do you set option other than at the beginning?

Comment: you mean JOptionPane? There is a showINputDialog box at the start of the while loop, and at the end of the while loop there is a showConfirmDialog followed by a showMessageDialog. is that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You try to get a character from the string whether or not there's anything in the string (like when a button is clicked). One option would be to check for button presses first.

Another would be to check the string, lowercased, against `"y"` or `"n"`, for example:

```
if (voteString.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
    // etc.
```

You still need to handle the `null` return value when the user cancels out of the dialog box. If they select "OK", it won't be `null`, but it *will* be empty, causing the out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: thanks, how do I correct this? do i try to set values for the buttons?

Comment: thanks again. netBeans just froze so i'm waiting on the computer for this, but i'm going to try changing my if statements to your way.

Comment: I edited the program, I still haven't quite solved the problem but does that look any closer to what you advised?

Comment: @JonW You still get the character. Also, the point of doing a lowerCase and comparing against it is so you only need to do a single compare for each command. If the user enters 'y' or 'Y' then `toLowerCase().equals('y')` will be true. You're doubling the work with no benefit.

Comment: Thank you! I just corrected that, sorry I misunderstood the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see here is that if you press "Cancel", there is a `NullPointerException` because the dialog will return `null` as the input in that case, yet you try to fetch the first character anyway. Otherwise it should (and does -- I compiled and ran it) work just fine.

Look at these two lines:

```
String voteString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 'Y' to vote yes, 'N'  to vote no, or 'Q' to quit voting", "Vote Now!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
vote = voteString.charAt(0);
```

There are two possible problems. First, let's say the user presses 'Cancel'. In that case, `showInputDialog()` returns `null`, and so `voteString` is `null`. That means that just calling `voteString.charAt(0)` will throw a `NullPointerException`. You must check for `null` first -- i.e.,

```
String voteString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 'Y' to vote yes, 'N'  to vote no, or 'Q' to quit voting", "Vote Now!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if (voteString == null) {
    // User has cancelled; let's quit
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The second problem is what happens if you press 'OK' without typing anything. In that case, `voteString` is zero characters long, and calling `charAt(0)` will throw a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, since there is no character at index 0. Again, you need to check for this. Adding to the previous example:

```
String voteString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 'Y' to vote yes, 'N'  to vote no, or 'Q' to quit voting", "Vote Now!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if (voteString == null) {
    // User has cancelled; let's quit
    System.exit(0);
} else if (voteString.length() == 0) {
    // This will just skip to the next go-round of the do/while loop, and prompt again
    continue;
}
```

Comment: thank you. yes, every button should be ignored as the q is the only one that can lead to the rest of the loop.

Comment: "OK" returns an empty string, not null :/

Comment: I did edit the program to try it Dave N's way, I am still having the error. Boy that's a lot of brackets. I do not have any errors besides NullPointerException when I hit cancel, thanks for checking.

Comment: Hi, I'm still having errors and I'm really confused. I reposted the code again after I corrected the errors I made trying to implement your advice, but I'm still getting the same errors. I'm sorry, I'm just stumped. Is there anything that just stands out that I'm doing wrong in this case?

Comment: I edited my post -- hope this helps. The changes you've made to the code don't help because you're still making the problematic `charAt` call on the original value of `voteString`, not the changed value.

Comment: thank you! i actually, with help of someone more experienced than i, found another way to get it working. how does this look to you?

Comment: Not great; if you `continue` when `voteString` is `null`, then the "Cancel" button doesn't do anything, which would be kind of annoying. Also the initial assignment of `""` to `voteString` is pointless. But the important thing is that you're checking for `null` or zero-length before calling `charAt()`, and that's not actually another way; that's exactly what both @DaveNewton and I were saying to do.

Comment: The reason that the cancel button and x button don't work is that the only thing that is supposed to be able to close the program is the letter q. The cancel isn't supposed to exit the program in the first place, according to the homework. I see that that was what you were suggesting. Thanks, sorry I misunderstood you in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

As others have mentioned, you don't correctly handle the situation where there is no text entered. Specifically, if you click 'ok', then voteString will be whatever is in the field (ie, the empty string). If you click cancel, then voteString will be null.

One way you could handle this is by setting voteString to a default value if either of these conditions is detected:

```
if (voteString == null || voteString .equals("")) voteString = "q";
```

Some other things: you don't ever update totalVotes.

You could use

```
vote = Character.toLowerCase(voteString.charAt(0))
```

to get the entered character. You could even use a different kind of dialog (that allows a yes/no/cancel button selection), rather than entered text.

If your you could use a switch(vote) block to choose between the entered text.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I should add that the dialog boxes I used are required by the assignment, and that setting voteString to "q" by default probably is not what my professor wants. For the sake of doing it though, I put it into my program and it did not solve the problem (did I do something wrong there?).

Comment: also, can you explain what you mean by I do not update totalVotes? what else do i need to do? it adds up the votes at the end. thanks.

Comment: I don't believe you understood the changes that I suggested. Firstly, you version two has severe issues with where the closing braces are. For example, you only check if the character is 'n' after you have determined that the character is 'y'.

Secondly, the idea of having a handler for the null/empty string is to use it BEFORE you do any other checks on the string.

Thirdly, the idea of converting the character to lowercase is so that you only have to perform a check on y, n, q: you don't have to check for Y, N, Q anymore.

Finally, vote up helpful answers even if they don't solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll edit it. Also, I thought that I had already rated your answer. There is no need to be terse about it. Have your upvote.